# Can I access the Deferred object from within an AJAX deferred callback?

Tags: jquery

Is there any way I can access the internal Deferred object from an ajax's success callback? I want to be able to pass abstract out an ajax call into a function, yet be able to wrap that function call in a $.when() and use reject() and resolve() to pass arguments back to my done() and fail() callbacks like so:

```
 $.when(makeCall())
 .done(function(data){
     //do something with data
  })
 .fail(function(message){
     //show error
  });

 function makeCall(){
     return $.ajax({
         url : //some url,
         success : function(data){
              if(!data.someCondition){
                 //i'd like to reject the internal deferred here
                 //and send it back an error message to my
                 //the callers fail method like reject('message')
              }
              else{
                 //i'd like to resolve the deferred here and 
                 //pass back the data to the callers done
                 //method like resolve(data)
              }
         }
     });
 }
```

Right now I'm wrapping makeCall() in another Deferred object and resolving or rejecting that one in the ajax callbacks but it feels like I should be able to do this without having that extra Deffered wrapper.

Comment: Instead of returning the result of `$.ajax` call, have you tried setting it to a variable and returning that variable? Then in success you could reject or resolve it, maybe. I haven't tried it myself, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @MrOBrian: That's basically the wrapping which he would like to avoid.

Comment: I actually tried that, doing something like `var dfd = $.ajax({})` but the ajax function only returned the promise, not the entire Deferred object where I could call resolve and reject.

Answer (score 1):

No, it has already been resolved or rejected at that point. You would have to create your own deferred to get this functionality.

```
$.when(makeCall())
 .done(function(data){
     //do something with data
  })
 .fail(function(message){
     //show error
  });

 function makeCall(){
     var def = $.Deferred();
     $.ajax({
         url : //some url,
         success : function(data){
              if(!data.someCondition){
                 // reject it
                 def.rejectWith(data.someCondition);
              }
              else{
                 // resolve it
                 def.resolveWith(data);
              }
         }
     });
     return def.promise();
 }
```

**Edit:** Sorry, I didn't realize that this is already what you tried and were trying to avoid. The problem is that in the success callback, the deferred object is already resolved. It can't be undone at that point.

**Edit:**
Woudln't it make more sense to have your server return an error status code rather than 200 in the event of an error? at that point you can parse the response text as json and handle the error appropriately without messing with the deferred objects any more than normal.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily have control of the response, say this was for a twitter search. If the twitter search fails you get a key called "error" in the json return, but the call comes back with a 200 status. I'd want to check if the return doesn't have a error key and return the data, otherwise pass an error message to the user.

Comment: I don't think you have any other option than wrapping it in a deferred object then. The internal deferred object is not exposed and I don't see a way to fail the deferred object before it gets resolved after the response is received short of overriding the `$.ajax` method.

Answer (score 0):

i needed to do this to prevent race conditions - i wanted to completely ignore some responses

Once I found I couldn't reject the original deferred I ended up doing something like this. Not ideal but worked for what I needed. Of course even if I had been able to reject the deferred (or create my own) that's probably not what I wanted either because it's not truly a fail condition either.

```
function makeCall()
{
     return $.ajax({
         url : //some url,
         success : function(data)
         {
              if (!data.someCondition)
              {
                 data.ignore = true;
              }
         }
     });
 }


 makeCall().done(function(data) 
 {
      if (data.ignore) 
      {
          return;
      }
 });
```